# Migrate render function vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Hello I'm migrating Vue 2 to Vue 3 and I've a problem with `render` function, because `render` in Vue 3 receives any arguments. I've read that I can use `setup` method instead, but it doesn't receive context argument that contains `data` and `children`.

Here my old code that I want migrate:

```
 render(h, { children, props, data }) {
   if (props.item) {
      const { first, last } = props;
      const reorderingClasses = Object.entries({ first, last })
        .filter(filterFalsy)
        .map(([key, value]) => `${key}-${value}`)
        .join(' ');

      const { xs, sm, md, lg } = props;
      const sizeClasses = Object.entries({ xs, sm, md, lg })
        .filter(filterFalsy)
        .map(
          ([key, value]) => `col-${key}${value !== 'auto' ? `-${value}` : ''}`
        )
        .join(' ');

      return (
        <div {...mergeData(data, { class: [reorderingClasses, sizeClasses] })}>
          <div class="box">{children}</div>
        </div>
      );

  return children
}
```

How I say in setup method I don't have context that contains `data` and `children`.

Docs: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/functional-components.html

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Did you get how to use those arguments(children,data) in setup?

Answer (score 0):

As you said you could use `setup` hook to render the template (JSX), you could use `slots.default` instead of `children` and reactive or ref instead of `data` :

```
setup(props, { slots }) {
   if (props.item) {
      const { first, last } = props;
      const reorderingClasses = Object.entries({ first, last })
        .filter(filterFalsy)
        .map(([key, value]) => `${key}-${value}`)
        .join(' ');

      const { xs, sm, md, lg } = props;
      const sizeClasses = Object.entries({ xs, sm, md, lg })
        .filter(filterFalsy)
        .map(
          ([key, value]) => `col-${key}${value !== 'auto' ? `-${value}` : ''}`
        )
        .join(' ');

      return ()=>(
        <div {...mergeData(data, { class: [reorderingClasses, sizeClasses] })}>
          <div class="box">{children}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  return ()=>slots.default()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Boussadjra Brahim but, Where can I obtain `data` property ? because in your reply you don't declare `data`.

Comment: you could use `reactive` or `ref` inside setup instead of data option